# Set the PTR Record correct

Tags: server, mail

I try to setup an PTR Record for my Domain. I can send mails but some emailservers reject my mail, because I have no PTR Record.

I try it the last days but not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Best regards

Here is my config.

```
cat /etc/bind/zones/master/db.domain.tld

$TTL 3h

@ IN SOA ns1.domain.tld. www.domain.tld. (
                                1       ;serial
                                3h      ;nach 3 stunden aktualisieren
                                1h      ;neuer versuch
                                1w      ;expire
                                1h )    ;negativecaching
;
@       IN      NS              ns1.domain.tld.
@       IN      NS              ns2.domain.tld.

@       IN      MX      10      mail.domain.tld.
larsmueller.net.        IN      A               81.169.xxx.xx
ns1                     IN      A               81.169.xxx.xx
ns2                     IN      A               81.169.xxx.xx
www                     IN      A               81.169.xxx.xx
mail                    IN      A               81.169.xxx.xx
ftp                     IN      CNAME           domain.tld.
cloud                   IN      CNAME           domain.tld.
office                  IN      CNAME           domain.tld.
ffsync                  IN      CNAME           domain.tld.
@                       IN      TXT             "v=spf1 mx ~all"
analytics               IN      CNAME           domain.tld.
_dmarc  IN TXT 14400 "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:server@domain.tld"
_domainkey  IN TXT "o=!;r=server@domain.tld"
2018._domainkey  IN TXT "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;t=s;s=email;p=... "

cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local

zone "domain.tld" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/master/db.domain.tld";
};
zone "xx.xxx.169.81.in-addr-arpa" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};

cat /etc/bind/db.192

$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.domain.tld. mail.domain.tld. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.domain.ltd.
xx.Xxx.169.81.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     ns1.domain.tld.
xx. Xxx.169.81.in-addr.arpa.    IN       PTR     domain.tld
xx.xxx.169.81.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     mail.domain.tld.
xx. Xxx.169.81.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     cloud.domain.tld.
Xx. Xxx. 169.81.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     analytics.domain.tld.

dig +short ptr  xx.xxx.169.81.in-addr.arpa.
domain.tld

root@mail:/etc/bind/zones/master# dig  xx.xxx.169.81.in-addr.arpa. AXFR
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: end of file
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way PTR records work, they have to be set by the entity that is running the nameserver for the subnet your are in.

Unless you have a /24 *and* have delegated NS records you *have* to contact your provider.

Based on your IP I'm guessing you have a virtual or physical machine housed by a German service provider. You should look up how to set reverse lookup in their documentation.